# How to execute some js code after click on exposed filter AJAX enabled submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, views

I have tried to update the input value of an exposed filter field before submit of the exposed filter through Js.

What I have tried

```
$('#edit-submit-phrases').on('click', function() {
  alert('check'); 
});
```

No alert message.

I also tried:

```
jQuery('#edit-submit-phrases').mousedown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ajaxStart() function, to execute something before  Ajax request begins:

```
 Drupal.behaviors.<themename/modulename> = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#edit-submit-phrases').on('click', function() {
      $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
        alert('check'); 
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Still getting the same issue. No alert message.

Comment: Are you using drupal.behaviours or just jquery ready?

Comment: i am using drupal.behaviours.

Comment: Works if i remove "$('#edit-submit-phrases').on('click', function() {
      $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {           });
    });

Comment: but you need it on that event only, right?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: For me its working, but not the first time. I will try to find out some solution

Comment: Thanks for your help it works now if remove $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {  }); . Even if on first time. Only the issue is that it Not working inside the panel page. working for other view page.